# randomForest prediction issue in r

Tags: r, random-forest, predict

I have been using the randomForest package for a classification model with only categorical factors as predictors. The predict function usually fails when there are new levels in the test that were not in the training. To overcome that, I have added the missing levels as follows:

```
mname<-get(model)

for ( k in 1:ncol(dataFrame))
{
  col<-names(dataFrame[k])
  modelLevels <- mname$forest$xlevels[[col]]
  orig<-levels(dataFrame[,k])
  misses <-setdiff(modelLevels,orig)
  origOrdered <- orig[order(match(orig,modelLevels))] # Not sure if ordering matters
  missOrdered <- misses[order(match(misses,modelLevels))] # Not sure if ordering matters
  if(length(misses) > 0) { levels(dataFrame[,k]) <- as.character(c(origOrdered,missOrdered)) }
}

prediction <- data.frame(predict(mname,dataFrame,type = "prob"))$X1
```

This prediction returns different values for the same input vector depending on the size of the dataframe provided for prediction.

For example, if I send a dataframe with only 2 rows it returns values of 0,0 whereas if I a pass a bigger dataframe with the same two rows included it throws a prediction of 0.066667 for the same two rows?

Could someone clarify what is the reason for this behavior? I am unable to share the data here.

Comment: Consider making a reproducible example using one of the datasets that come with R.

Comment: I have been trying to get a reproducible example but in vain. It doesn't seem to occur in some of the common datasets such as iris...I will keep trying and will add if I could get a reproducible example

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're doing here. You seem to be adding the levels to your testset instead of your training set? dataFrame is not used for training right?

Comment: Jellen, yes dataFrame is only the test set and does not include training data. We only have access to the model built using a different training data. I am trying to add the missing levels to the test data. The random forest prediction works without throwing any errors. However, the values are very different depending on whether test data has 2 rows or 200 rows

Comment: Added a couple of lines to show how I am getting the modelLevels. Missed it out in the original post

Comment: This is still entirely un-reproducible---and it seems more of a statistical question of why randomForest does what it does rather than a coding question. From your question I'm not even sure if the new levels are in the outcome or in a feature.

Comment: Can you reproduce your data similar to this data. Remove Levels the way shown.                                                                            library(ISLR)    set.seed(1)     index <- 1:nrow(Carseats) train_index=sample(index,length(index)/2)      train <- Carseats[train_index, ] test <- Carseats[-train_index, ]       newtrain <- train[train$ShelveLoc != 'Medium',]       newtrain$ShelveLoc <- factor(newtrain$ShelveLoc) ##remove Level= "Medium" from train model <-randomForest(Sales~.,data=newtrain,mtry=10,importance=TRUE) mname<-get("model")